# AskUbuntu can only log in via GMAIL LINK, but not by typing in email-pwd combo

Tags: support, bug, login

So I am trying to log into AskUbuntu with my email/pwd combo, and if I click GMAIL and then click on my email it logs me in, but if I type the same email, it says there is no account associated with this email.

I would like to be able to:

A) Sign in via email-pwd combo

B) Change email and move away from googles gmail. (Can I change the email associated with my account?)

Answer (score 1):

Login is really by OpenID (and similar methods, eg Google accounts, Facebook, etc) only. That said, StackExchange does have their own OpenID provider, if you don't already have one. So I would suggest:

- [Register for an Stack Exchange OpenID account](https://openid.stackexchange.com/),
- Add `https://openid.stackexchange.com` to [your logins](https://askubuntu.com/users/mylogins/395258),
- Optionally then delete your Google account from [your logins](https://askubuntu.com/users/mylogins/395258).

Comment: Thats a little complicated for what should be a simple change email login, but I will test a report back! For me and anyone else who happens upon this thread, I hate how much google is integrated/knows about my life. So i am trying to move away from that to my own hosted services.

Comment: It is a little complicated, but I think that's to be expected from a system that allows so many different login schemes. Actually, I take that back... 3 simple steps to fundamentally change how you log in to an entire network of sites is pretty simple :) Perhaps I'm coloured by knowing how complicated this stuff gets under the hood.